# Use dislocker without root access

Tags: mount, encryption, non-root-user

I installed `dislocker` using [this (excellent) answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617989/306960).

However I'd like to be able to mount and access an encrypter memory stick without root access. Presently, the root password is required in this line:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdb1 -u -- /media/bitlocker
```

Is there a workaround to avoid the need for `sudo`?